# Can't change datagrid text alignment (devexpress grid control)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I can't change the text of a devexpress gridcontrol's cells.
I have the code

`gdData.Columns[2].AppearanceCell.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;`

which used to work for my last project.
But now, I get an error-message saying that I can't assign something to ...HAlignment because it's readonly...
What do I miss?

Comment: what about `gdData.Columns[2].AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
gdData.Columns[2].AppearanceCell.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
gdData.Columns[2].AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: Thanks  - the line 'gdData.Columns[2].AppearanceCell.Options.UseTextOptions = true;' was the important one for me. I was getting inconsistent results before adding that, possibly because I'm building the grid programmatically, and cells don't initially have any text in them. I'm guessing that setting a cell value to a string automatically enables UseTextOptions.... maybe!